# How to acess a variable inside web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I have this web service:

```
public class Connect_to_db : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
public MySqlConnection myconn;

[WebMethod]
public void Connection1()
{

    string myconnection = "server = localhost;database = database2; port = 1234; username = root; password =";
    myconn = new MySqlConnection(myconnection);
    MySqlDataAdapter mydataadapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    myconn.Open();  //open the session
```

What i am trying to do is after i invoke the service to be able to use the variable **MySqlConnection myconn** like in every other regular class.
Example of my thinking:

```
     class A{ 
       public string Hello = "hello";
       }
       class B{
        void Goodbye(){
           A useA = new A;
           string Bye = A.Hello;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Maintaining database connections across web service calls is not such a great idea.  That is why there is Connection Pooling.  You would have to maintain the connection object in some global state on the server.  Not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use web config for storing your connection string. It is xml and easy to change later.

Comment: Yeah, what you are saying is true, what i want to achieve is to have MySqlConnection variable and not have to make a new connection each time.

Comment: Then put the code in a method and call it. Make it global if needed. Don't try to return same connection in that method, instead create a new one. Framework would handle it via connection pooling.